# Python App Engine : use app.yaml to control url handler

Tags: python, google-app-engine

When I control different type of pages, I move my code to another python file. But this way has disadvantage : each time I want to change url hander, I must comback to `main.py` to config bottom lines about url handler. for example :

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                               ('/thanks',ThanksHandler),
                               ('/unit2/signup',Signup),
                               ('/unit2/successful', LoginSuccess)], debug=True)
```

I try to config handler in `app.yaml` to prevent dis advantage.

I add file `blog.py` in same directory and in this file, I have Blog class. And here is my `blog.py` file:

```
class Blog(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("Hello")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/blog', Blog)], debug=True)
```

Here is original file:

```
> handlers:
> - url: /favicon\.ico   static_files: favicon.ico   upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /.*   script: main.app
```

and this new file `app.yaml`:

```
handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico   static_files: favicon.ico   upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /blog/.*   script: blog.app

- url: /.*   script: main.app
```

But when I goto: localhost:port/blog : 404: resource not found.

Please help me.

Thanks :)

Comment: Put your `/.*` handler last; that matches everything.

Comment: @Wooble after I change, i still see resource not found. Can you look at : `url: /blog/.*  script: blog.app`, does this url handler true for link localhost/blog ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The /blog/.* url specification from the yaml file does not match the url specification from the blog.py file (/blog). In particular the fact that /blog/.* requires the url to have a slash after blog.  If for example you use just /blog in both places it will work. Or you can use /blog/.* in both places.

The url specifiers are matched in the order in which they appear in the yaml file therefore in this particular case /blog/.* will not match on /blog but will match on the last (catch all really) /.* specifier and therefore main.py handler will be loaded and fail to match (no pattern in the call WSGIApplication constructor inside main.py).

Hope this helps.
-Silviu