# gae & python - setting different urls in yaml: 404 not found

Tags: python, web-services, google-app-engine, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to map different urls to different python scripts.

This is my yaml

```
application: myApp
version: 99
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /deleteCustomers
  script: test.app

- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"

builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

If I go to http://myapp.appspot.com/test, it says "404 not found"...
If I go to http://myapp.appspot.com, the right script is launched (main.app)

here is the same problem I have -> [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368106/python-app-engine-use-app-yaml-to-control-url-handler)
but the given solution is not working for me (even if it's the same code!!!)

Here's the handler ( to test the "2 path yaml", I've duplicated main.app, that holds customers and store classes plus mainhandler, renaming it to test.app. So both main.app and test.app are identical)

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        customers = Customers.all()
        stores = Stores.all()

        countCustomers= 0
        countStores= 0

        for p in customers:
            p.delete()
            countCustomers+= 1
        for p in stores:
            p.delete()
            countStores+= 1

        self.response.out.write("\nDeleted Customers: " + str(countCustomers))
        self.response.out.write("\nDeleted Stores: " + str(countStores))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

What I would like to achieve is split the customer and store deletion into two separate calls:

http://www.myapp.appspot.com/deleteCustomers and http://www.myapp.appspot.com/deleteStores

Thanks for any help in advance, best regards

Comment: try this: url:/test.* also could you maybe post the handler and the router that routes to the test handler.

Comment: Could you post the code in the test app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say both scripts are exactly the same then im assuming that you are using the same '/' to point to your MainHandler. Im not quite sure I understand you correctly but this is my attempt to help you out. In order to achieve splitting the store deletion and customer deletion into 2 different scripts you have to split the code into 2 different handlers mapped to each url something like:

```
class StoreDeletionHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    stores = Stores.all()

    countStores= 0

    for p in stores:
        p.delete()
        countStores+= 1

    self.response.out.write("\nDeleted Stores: " + str(countStores))        


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/deleteStores', StoreDeletionHandler)], debug=True)
```

the above would be in your main.py script routed with the following call in the yaml script:

```
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

and then for the second url in a different script test.py in this case:

```
class CustomerDeletionHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        customers = Customers.all()
        countCustomers= 0

        for p in customers:
            p.delete()
            countcustomers+= 1

        self.response.out.write("\nDeleted Customers: " + str(countCustomers))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/deleteCustomers', CustomerDeletionHandler)
], debug=True)
```

In your yaml file  you would map the url to the script via the following:

```
- url: /deleteCustomers
  script: test.app
```

Also take note that in order for all subsequent routes to be directed to the test.py script the URLs would have to start with the '/deleteCustomers' prefix

so something like this:

```
http://www.myapp.appspot.com/deleteCustomers/NewUrl1
http://www.myapp.appspot.com/deleteCustomers/SomethingElse
http://www.myapp.appspot.com/deleteCustomers/YetAnotherUrlForTestpy
```

All of the above would be directed to the test.py script. To redirect to the main.py script you simply route to anything else but the /deleteCustomers

```
http://www.myapp.appspot.com/ThisGoesToMain
http://www.myapp.appspot.com/deleteStores #also goes to main
http://www.myapp.appspot.com/deleteStores/YetAnotherUrlForMain
```

I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks Tkingovr, I didn't set the path value in the webapp2.WSGIApplication function. Now it works, thanks again!